# return in python error only returns one value

Tags: python, return

I am having some trouble with the `return`. I want to add numbers produced from the function to a list already created but when I return, I just get one value, but if I use print it is fine.

Does the `return` only produce one value?

```
def aFunction(n):
    for j in range(2,n):
        for i in range(2,j):
            if (j % i ==0):
                break
            else:
                return(j)
                break
print(aFunction(10))
```

Ok so this time i have edited the code slightly, how can i use p to divide n(which is an int)so that if no remainder remains i can append it to p?

```
    def function(n):
         p = [2,]
         for j in range(3,n):
            if (j // p) == 0:
                p.append(j)
         return(p)
   print(function(20))
```

Comment: if you tell return to return one value, it will return one value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `return` terminate the function, so when condition goes to `else` clause, it terminate the functions,

Use `generators`:-

```
def aFunction(n):
    for j in range(2,n):
        for i in range(2,j):
            if j % i == 0:
                break
            else:
                yield j
                break

print list(aFunction(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` terminates the function and returns the value.

You should add these values to a list and then print the list:

```
def aFunction(n):
    l = []
    for j in range(2,n):
        i in range(2,j):
            if (j % i != 0):
                l.append(j)
    return l

print(aFunction(10))
```

In Python, you can write a better code:

```
[j for j in range(2,n) for i in range(2,j) if j % i != 0]
```